# Trying to repaint all image pixels recursively

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to repaint all the image pixels recursively but it fails because the stack overflows. But why?

```
void go( short x, short y ) {

    if ( x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= _w || y >= _h ) return ;

    _image[ x ][ y ] = someColor;

    go( x + 1, y );
    go( x - 1, y );
    go( x, y - 1 );
    go( x, y + 1 ); 

}
```

Comment: Depends on the value of _w and _h and how big your stack is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function call will never stop.

```
void go( short x, short y ) {    

    if ( x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= _w || y >= _h ) return ;

    _image[ x ][ y ] = someColor;

    go( x + 1, y );
    go( x - 1, y ); 
    go( x, y - 1 );
    go( x, y + 1 ); 

}
```

If you call your function with `x=0,y=0` (`go( 0, 0 );`) it will do this

```
    _image[ 0 ][ 0 ] = someColor;    
    go( 1, 0 );
    go( -1, 0 ); 
    go( 0, -1 );
    go( 0, 1 );
```

OK now let's check the function call to `go( 1, 0 );`:

```
    _image[ 1 ][ 0 ] = someColor;    
    go( 2, 0 );
    go( 0, 0 );  //ohoh
    go( 1, -1 );
    go( 1, 1 );
```

So you can see that `go( 0, 0 )` calls `go( 1, 0 )` calls`go( 0, 0 )` calls `go( 1, 0 )` calls`go( 0, 0 )` calls `go( 1, 0 )` calls`go( 0, 0 )` calls `go( 1, 0 )` calls`go( 0, 0 )` calls `go( 1, 0 )` calls ....

That's why you have a stack overflow. You won't ever get out.

---

Why don't you just create 2 loops and iterate over these?
As your example always iterates `x` from `0` to `_w` and `y`from `0` to `_h`I would just get rid of these parameters at all.

You can just use this:

```
void go( short x, short y ) {    
    for(short x = 0; x < _w; x++) {
        for(short y = 0; y < _h; y++) {
            _image[ x ][ y ] = someColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I need to repaint all connected pixels (by the same color) from that which I've started...

Comment: Yeah? But you didn't do that in the first place. Is there any kind of repaint after setting the color of one pixel?

Comment: BTW thanks a lot for the explanation with the "So you can see that go( 0, 0 ) calls go( 1, 0 ) callsgo( 0, 0 ) calls go( 1, 0 ) callsgo( 0, 0 ) calls go( 1, 0 ) callsgo( 0, 0 ) calls go( 1, 0 ) callsgo( 0, 0 ) calls go( 1, 0 ) calls ...." :))) It really helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing one base case of initial value of `_image` array, as to stop re-filling same values over and over

```
if ( _image[x][y] != previousColor ) 
        return;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have never ending recursion.

For example, these two lines

```
go( x + 1, y );
go( x - 1, y );
```

are going to call each other forth and back.

This can be avoided using a flag for each cell that tells if the cell has been already repainted or not.

(Or you can use iteration instead of recursion as well).